# Is there a way to take a screenshot of my app without the background image?

Tags: ios, xcode6, screenshot

I have an application where I created a button to screenshot the app to the camera roll. I want to be able to hide the background image when the user takes a screen shot.

```
-(IBAction) screenShot: (id) sender{

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(sshot.frame.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage,nil, nil, nil);

}
```

I have this as my background

```
 [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back5.png"]]];
```

Is it possible to take a screenshot of the app where the background is no longer the image but just white color? I would also want to hide an image.view when using the screenshot as well.